# Setting counter for GCM in OpenSSL

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, openssl

Is there an API in OpenSSL,that I'm simply failing to recognize, which allows one to set the value of the counter for a given round of encryption in GCM (AES-128 if anyone cares)? Basically my desire is to be able to encrypt/decrypt random bytes in a file using the containing block numbers of the data as the counter values. As far as I can tell, the best you can do is set the counter when you establish the CTX by using a 16 byte IV instead of normal 12 byte. At the moment I seem pretty much constrained to encrypting/decrypting the file from the start and if I'm asked for a byte range which is, say, previous to the most recent operation, I have to abort and start over from the beginning.

Comment: Note that you must re-encrypt the whole file with a fresh IV every time the file is changed. If you only re-encrypt the changed part, you're reusing IVs, which is disastrous with GCM.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, ivlen, NULL);` with an `ivlen` value of 16? The counter can only be 16 bytes in total, after that it is simply increased as if it was a big-endian number.